# Как сокращать слово «части», когда речь идет о частях закона?

Tags: сокращение

Как сокращать слово «части», когда речь идет о частях закона?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во множественном числе принято сокращение "**чч.**" (см. "Русский орфографический словарь" под ред. Лопатина, приложение I. "Основные общепринятые графические сокращения") ([ссылка](https://popravilam.com/blog/sokrashcheniya-osnovnye.html#ch)).

Comment: Можно добавить адрес:  https://popravilam.com/blog/sokrashcheniya-osnovnye.html#ch

Comment: @Sharon да, спасибо, добавил. Я сам этим сайтом пользуюсь, но там написано, что "Сверен и исправлен редакторским бюро «По правилам»", и я не был уверен, достаточно ли авторитетна их выкладка, чтобы тут на неё ссылаться.

Answer (score 0):

Сокращения не нужны во фразах вида: "... в этой части преамбулы отмечено...". И безусловно желательны при перечислениях или уточнениях вида: "..в статье
(Nтакой-то) КЗоТ ч.третья п. шестой говориться о..."